# Why is return is ignored during output in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When I start a program that runs for a bit, say `make`, I could just type the next command in bash even before I got a prompt back and when the
first command finished, the second one was executed as if I had typed it later.

But suddenly this doesn't work any more. The additional command will be shown at the prompt after the first one finished but is not executed. If I type more commands, they are all shown at the prompt (without any space or newline between them).

Any idea what is at fault here or how I can figure it out myself?

Comment: *Something* changed, maymay. You'll help people answer if you try to remember what it was. Chances are that it was something you changed, rather than some random thing changing automatically. My wild guess: something to do with [the terminal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/). Maybe you were on the console before, and now you are `ssh`'d in, for example, and your SSH client doesn't have the right `TERM` value set.

Comment: Or maybe you've updated something in your system?

Answer (score 2):

That could happen if any command run by make does the equivalent of

```
stty igncr
```

However, you would see that typing return doesn't cause the cursor to go to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: Interactive bash uses readline for each input command, which switches to raw mode on entering and restores previous mode on exiting. So if some beast sets igncr or other weird flag, it will affect only programs started later, but not the bash itself.