# Where is the character escape sequence `\033[\061m` documented to mean bold?

Tags: colors, console, escape-characters

I am trying to write a program that runs a console program like gcc and displays its output in color. I used [`openpty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html) instead of `pipe` to pretend to be a character device and now get [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that carry color information. I tried some programs and they sometimes give me the code `CSI [ 49 m`. Both [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) and the [xterm escape code documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (search for `Ps = 4 9`) agree that code `CSI [ 49 m` means that I should be using the default background color.

However, debian's xterm and zsh as well as ubuntu's linux console disagree.
`printf '\033[\061mTest\n\033[\060m'` executed in a console like xterm should be printing "Test" with the default background color (`\033` is escape and `escape + [` make a CSI (Control Sequence Introducer) and `\061` is octal [which is 49 decimal](http://www.asciitable.com/)), but it actually prints "**Test**" in bold (and the `\061` at the end seems to mean "not bold anymore" but is documented neither on wikipedia nor in the xterm color code documentation). All consoles mentioned above agree on this.

There is [a list of color codes for various consoles and standards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/what-protocol-standard-is-used-by-terminals/5802), but none of them list `CSI 49 m` to mean "bold".

Where does this inconsistency come from? Where can I find a list of color codes that correspond to what any of xterm, zsh or the linux console are using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\61` is the octal code for the `1` character in ASCII, so `\e[\61m` or `\33[\61m` or `\33\133\61\155` or `\33[1m` is `<ESC>[1m`.

That's `CSI 1 m`. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) or [the `xterm` documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_).

```
$ printf '\e[\61m' | od -An -vto1 -tc
 033 133 061 155
 033   [   1   m
$ tput bold | od -An -vto1 -tc
 033 133 061 155
 033   [   1   m
```

For the *default background colour*, you'd need `\e[49m`, not `\e[\61m`. Those `1` and `49` numbers are meant to be expressed in their decimal string representation, not be the byte value.

Comment: Oh, so I've just been reading it wrong. Sorry.