# How do I use a serial port on Linux like a pipe or netcat?

Tags: serial-port

I have two computers with two serial ports: ttyS0 and ttyUSB0. (Actually they are on the same computer but that's just for testing).  The ports are connected via null modem cable. I want to be able to simply send bytes into one end and come out the other end, and vice versa.  Why doesn't the below work?:

```
# set both serial ports to 9600 8n1
# `-parenb` means no parity,
# `-cstopb` means 1 stop bit
# cs8 means 8 bits at a time 
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cs8 -cstopb -parenb 9600
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 cs8 -cstopb -parenb 9600

# in one terminal:
echo "asdf" > /dev/ttyUSB0

# in another terminal, this hangs and does nothing
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

I can do similar things with `netcat` and pipes very easily (below), so I feel something like the above should be possible as well.

```
mkfifo mypipe

# in one terminal
cat < mypipe

# in another. works as expected
echo "asdf" > mypipe
```

Comment: Your termios configuration is probably incomplete.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065389/forwarding-traffic-from-port-ttys3-to-ttyusb0-input-output-error/71134544#71134544

Comment: See also: [How to get file to a host when all you have is a serial console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312/114401)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't the below work?

```
# in one terminal:
echo "asdf" > /dev/ttyUSB0

# in another terminal, this hangs and does nothing
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

Because, as a rule, serial ports don't buffer data.  If there's no client app to receive the bytes landing on the serial port, they will simply be discarded.

As an experiment, try launching `minicom` or `cu` or another serial terminal program on the receiving computer, then run the `echo` command again on the transmitting computer.  Assuming the baud rate and framings line up, you should see "asdf" appear at the destination.

Comment: so if you were to run `cat /dev/ttyS0 &` or `cat /dev/ttyS0 > somefile &` and *then* echo/pipe to the device, you will see the data come out the other side. I suspect one could also use `mkfifo`, pipe from the serial port to the fifo buffer then read off the fifo as desired.

Comment: This answer is wrong, and doesn't answer the question.  The Linux kernel driver for the UART does buffer all received data for the termios subsystem.  See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).  Additionally, the command `cat < /dev/ttyS0` would create a *"client app to receive the bytes landing on the serial port"*.  A real reason for the hang could be misuse of canonical mode.

Comment: @sawdust, I added an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720397/114401

Answer (score 3):

> I want to be able to simply send bytes into one end and come out the other end, and vice versa. Why doesn't the below work?

I think it's because you simply need to switch the order: start the listener *first* and *then* send the data (just like you did in your own pipe example--you started listening *first*):

```bash
# Absolutely first, configure each port using `stty`, as you already
# do:

# set both serial ports to 9600 8n1
# `-parenb` means no parity,
# `-cstopb` means 1 stop bit
# cs8 means 8 bits at a time 
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 cs8 -cstopb -parenb 9600
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 cs8 -cstopb -parenb 9600

# THEN, do in this order

# first, in the receiving terminal, start listening
cat < /dev/ttyS0

# then, in a separate terminal for sending, send the data
echo "asdf" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I am pretty confident my answer is *procedurally* correct, meaning: if you blindly follow it, it will work.

But, the question still remains: *why*? Why do you have to start listening first? Doesn't the Linux kernel buffer for you? If so, shouldn't the data just be sitting there in the buffer ready to be read? Clearly it *isn't*, else writing first and reading second would work. But, it doesn't.

I'm guessing here, but I think the answer here is that when the driver receives data, it first checks to see if the receiving pseudo-file at `/dev/ttyUSB0` is in an opened state, held open by another process. If *not*, the driver discards the data, since no one is there to receive it. If the file *is* open, it allows the process which has the file open to read the buffered data.

### Key differences between sending over a serial port and sending over an inter-process-communication (IPC) pipe

This is different from your pipe example where you make a pipe with `mkfifo`. I just checked, and in the pipe example, you can either start listening in one terminal first *or* send to the pipe in the other terminal first. It doesn't matter. It works in both cases.

If you write first, the write blocks and waits until a process reads from the pipe. If you read first, the read blocks and waits until a process writes to the pipe. This is confirmed by the Linux documentation for C's `mkfifo()` function, which the bash `mkfifo` is almost certainly based on. [See `man 3 mkfifo`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html) (emphasis added):

> Once you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any
> process can open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an
> ordinary file.  **However, it has to be open at both ends**
> ***simultaneously* before you can proceed to do any input or output**
> **operations on it.**  Opening a FIFO for reading **normally blocks**
> until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and
> vice versa.

This is different from how serial ports behave, however, probably because the serial ports on each end are expected to be controlled from *different* machines, unlike FIFO pipes, whose read and write ends are expected to be controlled *from the same machine*. In the latter case, the kernel can easily track when one process tries to read and another tries to write, since it controls both ends of the pipe...hence, it allows either to block.

In the serial port case, however, the kernel has no idea if another device is listening or going to send, so it won't block on sending. To be clear: when writing to a pipe, the write is blocked until a listener is present. But, when writing to a serial port, the computer *has no means of checking if a listener is present*, so it *never blocks!* It just sends. **Instead of blocking if no listener is present, data sent over serial while no-one is listening is just lost.** Again, this is different from pipes, where my experiment and the documentation above both confirm that a process trying to send data over a pipe *is blocked until a listener is present to read that data.*

### References and "see also":

1. I'm actively learning as I write this, documenting various findings in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here, in case you're interested: [serial_terminals_README.md](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_apps/serial_terminals_README.md).
2. My demo code: [eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash/ipc_pipe_fifo.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/ipc_pipe_fifo.sh)
3. `man 3 mkfifo`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html